# How can you exclude the pseudo element &shy; when collecting text using textContent?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I collect text from an HTML file using the `textContent` method.
I beliefe that the pseudo element `&shy;` is copied as well since I cannot replace words that contain this element. All words that contain `&shy;` (which is not visible) cannot be replaced with the actual word.
I tried to first replace `%shy;` using `.replace((&shy;/g, "")` but it will still not work.

Example:

I cannot replace `"efter&shy;som"` using `.replace(/eftersom/g, "???")`
As said the ­ element is not visible after collecting it with `.textContent`, but it seems to be there.

I tried multiple regular expressions like:

```
.replace(new RegExp(`(\\W)(${firstWord.replace(/&shy;/gi, "")})(\\W)`, "gi"), "$1???$3")
```

where `firstWord` is a variable.

Comment: A soft hyphen is a character, not a pseudo element.

Comment: Do you see the literal string `&shy;` in your HTML string, or are those invisible chars with Unicode code point of `U+00AD`? Use `od -c` on the file to examine invisible chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works - this should remove all the `&shy;`s on your page:

```
console.log(document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\u00AD/g, ''));
```

This works by by searching for the Unicode character U+00AD.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answer didn't work try using this one, which includes the &shy and the decimal version of the soft-hyphen (&#173).

```
.replace(/(\&shy;|­|&#173;)/gi, "");
```

This have been answered before in this question.
[Remove &shy; (soft hyphen) entity from element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043050/remove-shy-soft-hyphen-entity-from-element)